# Tikz opacity does not work with beamer, works for article

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, transparency

I'm using Miktex 2.9 + pdflatex and I'm having a bizarre issue. Whenever I use opacity for Tikz in beamer it does not work even if the same code works perfectly fine for a regular article document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,bbm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx, graphics}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{psfrag,pst-node,subfigure,rotating, amsmath, bbm, amsthm, amssymb, amsthm, setspace, picture, epsfig, amsfonts, upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{tikz} % for venn diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,shapes.misc, positioning,shapes.geometric,arrows,matrix,fit,calc,arrows.meta, trees, hobby}
%\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

%%% Added on 04/13/2009 for getting multiple rows in Table 4.
\usepackage{multirow}



\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=66,
        shape border rotate=90,
        draw,
        thick,
        fill=blue!20,
        node distance=5cm,
        rounded corners=60pt,
        opacity=0.6,
        minimum height=6.25cm
    }
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
   \pgfsetlayers{background,%
                 main,%
                 foreground%
                 }


\setbeameroption{hide notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]

% get rid of junk
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone} % don't show bookmarks on initial view

% page number
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[20pt]{\color{gray}
          \scriptsize\insertframenumber}}}\hspace*{5pt}}

% add a bit of space at the top of the notes page
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}}


\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{{\textendash}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subitem}{size=\footnotesize}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}


\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\scriptsize}


\begin{document}


%\section[Content]{}
%\frame{\tableofcontents}

%\section{Introduction}



% ====================================================================== %



\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\resizebox{.7\textwidth}{!}{% <------ Don't forget this %
\tikzstyle{background rectangle}=
[draw=blue!8,fill=blue!8,rounded corners=1.5ex]
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath,show background rectangle]
% \node (1) [draw, rounded rectangle] {none};
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6.2cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.6}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {\Large {}};
  \node [venn circle = yellow] (C) at (0:4cm) {\Large {}};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {\Large {}};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=0.9/3,B=1/2 ) {\Large$A \cap B$}; %$$
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {\Large$A \cap C$};   %$$
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=0.9/3 ) {\Large$B \cap C$};   %$$
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1.1/3,B=1/3,C=1.1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};%$$
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=3/4,B=-1/12) {{\Large$A$}}; %$$
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:C=3/4,B=-1/12 ) {{\Large$C$}}; %$$
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=-1/9,B=4/5 ) {{\Large$B$}};  %$$


  \node[label=right:\Large$None$] (Non) at (5,5)  {}; %$$

  %\draw[thick,green]  (-3.5,0) --(7.5,0);
  %\draw[thick,green]  (0,-3.5) --(0,6.9);

  \path(-3.5,0) --(7.5,0);
  \path(0,-3.5) --(0,6.9);
\end{tikzpicture}   
}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

and then with article, everything is fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bbm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx, graphics}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{psfrag,pst-node,subfigure,rotating, amsmath, bbm, amsthm, amssymb, amsthm, setspace, picture, epsfig, amsfonts, upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{tikz} % for venn diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,shapes.misc, positioning,shapes.geometric,arrows,matrix,fit,calc,arrows.meta, trees, hobby}
%\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

%%% Added on 04/13/2009 for getting multiple rows in Table 4.
\usepackage{multirow}



\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=66,
        shape border rotate=90,
        draw,
        thick,
        fill=blue!20,
        node distance=5cm,
        rounded corners=60pt,
        opacity=0.6,
        minimum height=6.25cm
    }
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
   \pgfsetlayers{background,%
                 main,%
                 foreground%
                 }




\begin{document}


%\section[Content]{}
%\frame{\tableofcontents}

%\section{Introduction}



% ====================================================================== %


\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\resizebox{.7\textwidth}{!}{% <------ Don't forget this %
\tikzstyle{background rectangle}=
[draw=blue!8,fill=blue!8,rounded corners=1.5ex]
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath,show background rectangle]
% \node (1) [draw, rounded rectangle] {none};
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6.2cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.6}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {\Large {}};
  \node [venn circle = yellow] (C) at (0:4cm) {\Large {}};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {\Large {}};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=0.9/3,B=1/2 ) {\Large$A \cap B$}; %$$
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {\Large$A \cap C$};   %$$
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=0.9/3 ) {\Large$B \cap C$};   %$$
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1.1/3,B=1/3,C=1.1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};%$$
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=3/4,B=-1/12) {{\Large$A$}}; %$$
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:C=3/4,B=-1/12 ) {{\Large$C$}}; %$$
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=-1/9,B=4/5 ) {{\Large$B$}};  %$$


  \node[label=right:\Large$None$] (Non) at (5,5)  {}; %$$

  %\draw[thick,green]  (-3.5,0) --(7.5,0);
  %\draw[thick,green]  (0,-3.5) --(0,6.9);

  \path(-3.5,0) --(7.5,0);
  \path(0,-3.5) --(0,6.9);
\end{tikzpicture}  
}
\end{figure}




% ====================================================================== %


\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

Comment: Your example is very far from being minimal. I get the correct opacity with your code stripped down to the essential (beamer/tikz/frame/tikzpicture with venn nodes, no extra styles).

Comment: If you get the correct opacity, could you at least post what you did to get it?

Comment: Remove `pst-node`

Comment: Thanks, samcarter. Removing pst-node did the trick. Why was that an issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Removing `pst-node` solves the issue.

Don't collect packages - look for another collecting passion, I heard stamps are good to collect. Or maybe this:

[image]

Borrowed from [@PauloCereda](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31504253#31504253), I hope you don't mind.

You should only use the packages necessary for the specific document, to prevent such problems and don't just copy your preamble from article to beamer. This reduces the risk for such problems.

Besides this

- as things like `\usepackage{xcolor}`, `\usepackage{graphicx, graphics}` (and don't load both, one is enough :) are already provided by beamer, loading them again might only lead to option clashes.
- same for the packages you load multiple times, e.g. `amsmath, bbm, amsthm, amssymb, amsthm,`

[image]