# Packages not working together

Tags: packages

I have a problem with compiling a LaTeX document into PDF.

The code itself seems to be correct, as it compiles smoothly at sharelatex.com, but it doesn't work on my computer (I am using TeXstudio).

The problem seems to come from the fact that me and other people sharing the document have copied some `\usepackage` commands we typically use, which don't work together. The errors are

> undefined control sequence

and

> package error: this package cannot be used in cooperation with others

The problem seems to concern all the packages as I try to remove some of them at random. The packages I use are:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.00in, right=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,

}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: You should not use `subcaption` and `subfig` together. Remove one of them and use always the other one. And you load several packages more than once. It would be better to avoid this.

Comment: Only use the packages you need for a specific document, don't randomly collect them. Don't load them multiple times and pay attention to the order. Things like `hyperref` should be loaded towards the end, `babel` near the beginning.

Comment: For suggestions of other collectibles see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326170/36296

Answer (score 2):

You load `geometry` twice with different options, not a good idea.

You load `appendix` twice with different options, not a good idea.

Fixing those, then the mwe compiles for me with naive contents.