# How to replace content over previous material in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am making a list in beamer that I want replaced on the same slide with another list using the `\itemize` command.  I am using `\uncover` so that the listed items show up one-by-one.  Once the first list is finished, I want it to disappear and then be replaced by the new list.  My problem is that the new list appears below where the first list would have. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{itemize}
    \uncover<1-4>{\item (CONTENT 1)}

    \uncover<2-4>{\item (CONTENT 2)}

    \uncover<3-4>{\item (CONTENT 3)}
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{itemize}
    \uncover<6->{\item (CONTENT A)}

    \uncover<7->{\item (CONTENT B)}

    \uncover<8->{\item (CONTENT C)}
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why you not use new frame with the same title for new list? And then simple `\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item  (CONTENT A)
\item (CONTENT B)
\item (CONTENT C).
\end{itemize}` ?

Comment: I can try that.  I guess I was worried doing that with what I am actually working on would get complicated and hard to keep track of.

Comment: You can use `\onslide` or `\only` etc. However, I don't really see the point here as you're not replacing just some content, but all of it, so a new `frame` is more straightforward.

Comment: Why are you loading `color` twice? Don't even load it once: it is entirely pointless here. You don't need `graphicx` either, but that is not misleading in the same way, so innocuous enough. I would not recommend `multicol` with `beamer`. Why do you think this necessary?

Comment: I'm sorry.  Part many of the packages are simply copy-and-paste from an outside template.  I included them all just in case something doesn't compile.

Comment: @gorzardfu That's a really bad habit. You should only use the packages you need for a project, don't collect packages, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326170/36296

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exchange content, you can use `\alt<...>{...}{...}`

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\alt<1-4>{
    \begin{itemize}
    \uncover<1-4>{\item (CONTENT 1)}

    \uncover<2-4>{\item (CONTENT 2)}

    \uncover<3-4>{\item (CONTENT 3)}
    \end{itemize}
}{
    \begin{itemize}
    \uncover<6->{\item (CONTENT A)}

    \uncover<7->{\item (CONTENT B)}

    \uncover<8->{\item (CONTENT C)}
    \end{itemize}
}
\pause[8]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @gorzardfu You're welcome! And please remember to clean up your list of packages!

Comment: Okay, I'll edit this for future users. :)

Comment: @gorzardfu No need to edit, but please do your self a favour and do it in your own document.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip.  Also, is there a way to make things alternate more than once?  Suppose I wanted to replace the second item list with a third list in the same place.

Comment: @gorzardfu You could probably nest the `alt` environments.